# Remove the default date in jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

My datepicker jQuery I need to delete the default day so I removed the class. Are there another solution?

```
$('#calendar .ui-datepicker-days-cell-over').removeClass('ui-datepicker-days-cell-over');
$('#calendar .ui-state-hover').removeClass('ui-state-hover');
$('#calendar .ui-datepicker-current-day').removeClass('ui-datepicker-current-day');
$('#calendar .ui-state-active').removeClass('ui-state-active');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the default day is set to `null`. I don't know why your default day is set to another day. But you can reset it to null by:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
  defaultDate: null
});
```

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xie_qianyue/khhoqkcf/1/).

Comment: Thx, i executes "$(calendar).datepicker( "option", "defaultDate", null );" after the option beforeShowDay and it's work.

But now when I click on the button of the next month and I come back to the current month , the first date is not " unselectable " is defined as "current - day". Why ?

Comment: Can you show a jsFiddle? I can't get what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <style type="text/css">
       .ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-datepicker-days-cell-over.ui-datepicker-today a
       {
        background: #e6e6e6 url("images/ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 50% !important;
        border: 1px solid #d3d3d3 !important;
        color: #555555 !important;
       }

      </style>
      <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
      });

      </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $("#datepicker").focus ( function(){
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Change date picker action from on load to on click or on focus so that function will stop generate date on page load, with this default place holder will display.

Change script with bellow updates.

Comment: add explanation to your answer, don't post just code

Answer (score 0):

Change date picker action from on load to on click or on focus so that function will stop generate date on page load, with this default place holder will display.

change script with bellow updates.

```
<script>
  $("#datepicker").focus ( function(){
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker('setDate', null);
```